# error accessing file pointer in a multi-threaded program

Tags: c, file-io, parallel-processing, cilk

What I want to ask is part of some big code but I will try to make it as short as possible. I will first explain the relevant code snippets from my code first and then the error I am getting.

From `main.c` inside main function:

```
cilk_for ( line_count = 0; line_count != no_of_lines ; ++line_count )
{
     //some stuff here
     for ( j=line_count+1; j<no_of_lines; ++j )
     {
         //some stuff here
         final_result[line_count][j] = bf_dup_eleminate ( table_bloom[line_count], file_names[j], j );
         //some stuff here
     }
     //some stuff here
}
```

`bf_dup_eleminate` function from `bloom-filter.c` file:

```
int bf_dup_eleminate ( const bloom_filter *bf, const char *file_name, int j )
{
    int count=-1;
    FILE *fp = fopen (file_name, "rb" );
    if (fp)
    {
        count = bf_dup_eleminate_read ( bf, fp, j);
        fclose ( fp );
    }
    else
    {
        printf ( "Could not open file\n" );
    }
    return count;
}
```

`bf_dup_eleminate_read` from `bloom-filter.c` file:

```
int bf_dup_eleminate_read ( const bloom_filter *bf, FILE *fp, int j )
{
    //some stuff here
    printf ( "before while loop. j is %d ** workder id: **********%d***********\n", j, __cilkrts_get_worker_number());
    while (/*somecondition*/)
    {/*some stuff*/}
    //some stuff
}
```

This is a multi-threaded application (I ran it by enforcing it to use two threads) and I can be sure that the first thread reaches the `printf` statement(as it is outputted with thread information). Now `gdb` tells me that you have the following error

`0x0000000000406fc4 in bf_dup_eleminate_read (bf=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7edba58>, 
    fp=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7edba50>, 
    j=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7edba4c>) at bloom-filter.c:536`

`Line 536` is `int bf_dup_eleminate_read ( const bloom_filter *bf, FILE *fp, int j )`

The error message is pretty clear but I didnt get that why is it happening. I cannot think of a reason why this is happening. It is sure that the file opened (as error message in function `bf_dup_eleminate` was not printed). Also I have a believe that if two thread are executing same lines of code than they will have separate instantiations for all local variables. Given that what can be the problem.

Any help is appreciated!!

P.S.: `cilk_for` keyword is just a construct to spawn threads at runtime.

The program runs when number of threads to use is made 1.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when you pass variables by reference, I mean table_bloom[line_count], it's passing the pointer to all the threads. So all thread are trying to access the pointer value at the same time. You could try making a copy of each argument and then pass it to the bf_dup_eleminate_read.
not tested code:

```
int bf_dup_eleminate ( const bloom_filter *bf, const char *file_name, int j )
{
    bloom_filter *t_bf = bf;

    int count=-1;
    FILE *fp = fopen (file_name, "rb" );
    if (fp)
    {
        count = bf_dup_eleminate_read (t_bf, fp, j);
        fclose ( fp );
    }
    else
    {
        printf ( "Could not open file\n" );
    }
    return count;
}
```

or this doesn't work, try making a hard copy of the each argument:

```
    bloom_filter t_bf = *bf; //forgot how struct copying is done
    char *t_filename = strdup(filename);
    int t_j = j; //not required
```

if you cannot make a copy, then maybe use a mutex. see [link](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html).

Comment: This can make sense but did you see the error `GDB` gave it is talking about the `file pointer` and `j` specifically

Comment: It says bf=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7edba58>, fp=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7edba50>, j=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7edba4c>        Thats all right?

Comment: I am a bit confused here with "Thats all right?". Could you please elaborate

Comment: Also one more doubt, you have written `bloom_filter *t_bf = bf;`
    `char *t_filename = filename;` but not used them I think what you meant was to pass them to the function `bf_dup_eleminate_read` and open the file with `t_filename`. If so please edit the answer.

Comment: The GDB error states it cannot access memory for all passed arguments. bf, fp, and j. It's not only file pointer and j.